# Angular2 event binding, can it be done without '(' & ')', Property binding can it be done without '[' & ']'

Tags: html, dom, angular, angular2-forms

I wonder if there is any way to achieve the event and the property binding without using **parenthesis** or **brackets**?
Reference : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#event-binding

```
<input [value]="currentHero.firstName"
       (input)="currentHero.firstName=$event.target.value" >
```

- In Angular2 for event-binding we need '(event-type)', looking for some way to perform the same
- In Angular2 for property-binding we need '[property-value]', looking for some way to perform the same functionality.

   **Can this be done the way normal DomElements, because '[]' & '()' is not a valid Html attributes..!**

**Edit:**
function:

```
getDomElement(model:Object){
//...some logic to control the elemet generation
return {text-type-InputElement};// ..only returns elemnts(eg: <input type="text"/>)
}
var type = getDomElement(elem).type; // .. will give us TEXT
var tagName = getDomElement(elem).tagName;//.. will give us INPUT
```

Using the above returned DomElement, I am trying to perform **element.setAttribute("[(ngModel)]","model.firstName")**.
Which is not possible, any alternatives to achieve this.

Comment: What do you need this for? These parens and brackets never reach the DOM.

Comment: Your premise is wrong. `[]()` are valid characters in HTML5 attribute names https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am looking to use the setAttribute() for the existing domElement, to extend for custom events, is there any alternative to do it. The source I have is only elementRef.nativeElement(~which is a domElement).

Comment: @Harry Ninh , I was not aware of that, in my case, an object of type [Object HtmlElement] will be a source, from your advice the object couldn't be an HTML5, can we convert it dynamically to HTML5.. ?

Comment: I'm confused. How is your last comment related to your question? What do you mean with "to extend for custom events" - what does need to be extended for custom events? Why would you use `setAttribute()` for inputs and registering event listeners?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I tried to split the dom elements from the A2 bindings. Only in certain case, if the condition satisfies I need to bind the model. else just an empty HtmlElement has to be shown on screen.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input bind-value="currentHero.firstName"
       on-input="currentHero.firstName=$event.target.value" >
```

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html (search for "canonical")

Comment: Your `setAttribute` comment confuses me. This won't work if you add it dynamically. Angular2 doesn't process anything that's added dynamically to the DOM. Only when you add this statically to a components template will it be processed.

Comment: it appears like, <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" bind-value="John" on-input="mmObj.firstName=$event.target.value">, on the screen an input textbox and when inspecting the textBox.

Comment: but no value, on screen, just an empty text box...!

Comment: You need to provide more information. I can't make any sense of your comments. I have no way of knowing what you're actually doing. Please edit your question and add your code there and explain the actual and expected behavior. Otherwise I don't know how to provide support.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126798/discussion-between-peaceuser-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Adding `[]`, `()`, `[()]`, `{{}}`, `on-xxx`, or `bind-xxx` dynamically to the DOM doesn't buy you anything. As mentioned above Angular doesn't process this if it is added dynamically to the DOM. You need to literally write it to the template of a component otherwise Angular2 won't even notice it was added. Angular also doesn't create components or directives for HTML added dynamically later.

Comment: You can build components dynamically if you need to accomplish something like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960 or you can use imperative code to register event listeners `element.addEventListener()` or write to components properties.

Comment: when there is no binding happens at all, addEventListner() purpose something?, lemme say for ng-change?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `ng-change`. `ng-change` looks like Angular1 (I haven't used Angular1 myself). If the HTML is added dynamically (`[innerHTML]="..."` or similar), then there won't be an `ng-change` event, but `addEventlistener()` would work for DOM events like `click`, `change`, ...